# Tcl: Copy all files in directory structure to a single location outside

Tags: tcl

I need to recursively find all files that end with .vhd inside a directory and then copy all of them to the directory where the tcl script has been called from. This is the same directory that the user is in when the TCL script is invoked.

So what I need to so to find all .vhd files recursively and regardless of where they are, copy all of them into a single folder. I tried to use glob search but it seems perhaps that it cannot do recursive search. How can this be achieved using TCL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fileutil::findByPattern`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.md#13) from tcllib to get the file names and copy them in a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require fileutil

proc copy_tree {from_dir pat to_dir} {
    foreach f [::fileutil::findByPattern $from_dir -glob -- $pat] {
        file copy -force -- $f $to_dir
    }
}

copy_tree some/dir *.vhd destination/
```

Comment: Is the package fileutil a standard part of all TCL shells?

Comment: It's part of [tcllib](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/) which is an extra "standard" library.

Comment: While I am grateful for your answer, I have found that the fileutil does not exist in the Libero SoC TCL shell. What alternate exists?

Comment: @quantum231 See my answer for a standalone alternative.

Comment: There is no need for the explicit `foreach` loop, isn't it? Simplify to`file copy -force -- {*}[::fileutil::findByPattern $from_dir -glob -- $pat] $to_dir` ... better use a llength check, though. See my answer.

Comment: @mrcalvin If you know it'll always return at least one file, sure.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can provide for a `tcllib` installation for your environment, you will have to implement the directory traversal yourself. Below is but one of the many options (adapted from [`ftw_4` at Tclers' Wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Directory+recursion); this assumes Tcl 8.5+):

```
proc copy_tree {from_dirs pat to_dir} {
  set files [list]
  while {[llength $from_dirs]} {
    set from_dirs [lassign $from_dirs name]
    set from_dirs [list {*}[glob -nocomplain -directory $name -type d *] {*}$from_dirs]
    lappend files {*}[glob -nocomplain -directory $name -type f $pat]
  }

  if {[llength $files]} {
    file copy -force -- {*}$files $to_dir
  }
}
```

---

Some remarks: This implements an iterative, depth-first directory traversal, *and*

- `glob` is used twice, once to collect sub-directories, once to collect the source files.
- `file copy` is executed just once (for the entire collection of source files), not for every source file.
- The `-nocomplain`  flag on `glob` is convenient, but maybe not useful in your scenario (whatever that might be).